# AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'edit'

Tags: python, asynchronous, pycord

I am making a discord bot:

There is an async function that corresponds to a slash command. I have another function called count():

```py
async def count(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i
```

and in the slash command function:

```py
msg = ctx.respond("")
for i in count(n):
    await msg.edit(i)
```

I got the following error:
`discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable`

So I looked up some suggestions on Stack Overflow and changed my code to:

```py
global msg
msg = ctx.respond("")

async def counnnt(n):
    async for i in count(n):
        await msg.edit(i)

asyncio.run(counnnt(n))
```

Finally I got this error:
`discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'edit'`

(obviously I am not doing count() in my bot but something very similar)
I appreciate any suggestions :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, `ctx.respond` is `async` so needs to be `await`ed:

```py
msg = await ctx.respond("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use;

```
msg.edit_original_response(content="A")
```

Comment: Please explain how your code addresses the problem. Code only answers are hard to understand.

Comment: The reason is already written in the error code. Respond does not have an edit function. This is for editing respond messages.